# Broken image slider

Tags: html, css

I making a new website for my company and making my own slider. The slider works but the images aren't displaying properly:[image: part1][image: part2]
Is there a way to fix this easily?
the source code: (most of the code is repeated for each image)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style_sheet.css" rel="stylesheet" title="style sheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
        <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
        <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
        <span id="slider-image-4"></span>
        <span id="slider-image-5"></span>
        <span id="slider-image-6"></span>
        <span id="slider-image-7"></span>
        <span id="slider-image-8"></span>
        <span id="slider-image-9"></span>
        <div class="image-holder">
            <img src="../bee colouring page.jpg" class="slider-image" />
            <img src="../lol/Front cover.jpg" class="slider-image" />
            <img src="../lol/Ida front cover.jpg" class="slider-image" />
            <img src="../lol/ida.jpg" class="slider-image" />
            <img src="../lol/IMG_4305.JPG" class="slider-image" />
            <img src="../lol/IMG_4464[1].JPG" class="slider-image" />
            <img src="../lol/IMG_4465[1].JPG" class="slider-image" />
            <img src="../lol/IMG_4466[1].JPG" class="slider-image" />
            <img src="../lol/ltb team.JPG" class="slider-image" />
        </div>
        <div class="button-holder">
            <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>
          <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>
          <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>
          <a href="#slider-image-4" class="slider-change"></a>
          <a href="#slider-image-5" class="slider-change"></a>
          <a href="#slider-image-6" class="slider-change"></a>
          <a href="#slider-image-7" class="slider-change"></a>
          <a href="#slider-image-8" class="slider-change"></a>
          <a href="#slider-image-9" class="slider-change"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

style sheet:

```
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.slider-holder
        {
            width: 800px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: yellow;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        .image-holder
        {
            width: 2400px;
            background-color: red;
            height: 400px;
            clear: both;
            position: relative;
            
            -webkit-transition: left 2s;
            -moz-transition: left 2s;
            -o-transition: left 2s;
            transition: left 2s;
        }
        
        .slider-image
        {
            float: left;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        #slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: 0px;
        }
        
        #slider-image-2:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -800px;
        }
        
        #slider-image-3:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -1600px;
        }
        
        #slider-image-4:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -2400px;
        }
        
        #slider-image-5:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -3200px;
        }
        
        #slider-image-6:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -4000px;
        }
        
        #slider-image-7:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -4800px;
        }
        
        #slider-image-8:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -5600px;
        }
        
        #slider-image-9:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -6400px;
        }
        
        .button-holder
        {
            position: relative;
            top: -20px;
        }
        
        .slider-change
        {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 10px;
            width: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: brown;
        }
```

I would just like to know how to get the images in the right place, hidden from the page until the slider gets to them.
If it is easier and someone could supply a working code rather than fixing this code it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this code to the main div, it works better with 800x400 images:

```
<div class="slider-holder">
```